# Python 3.10 deprecation warning for distutils

Tags: python, python-3.x, distutils, deprecation-warning

```
DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
```

Is it something that I should worry about?
Which import should I use to replace the `from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree` line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change from:

```
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
copy_tree(loc_source, loc_destination)
```

To:

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree(loc_source, loc_destination)
```

Or, to replace existing files and folders:

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree(loc_source, loc_destination, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree